# Put label above boxplot for each category with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a `geom_text` above each boxplot according their original dataset. Though, I cannot separate them properly.

To be more precise, this how my dataset look like:

```
set.seed(1)

example <- data.frame("db" = c(rep("Db1", 3), rep("Db2", 2), rep("Db1", 3), rep("Db2", 2)),
                      "variable" = c(rep("Var1", 5), rep("Var2", 5)),
                      "value" = c(runif(3), (runif(2)+0.5), (runif(3)+1), (runif(2)+1.5)),
                      "group" = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 2), rep("a", 3), rep("b", 2)))
```

And this is the code I produced:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(example, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = db)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("firebrick3", "dodgerblue")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("firebrick3", "dodgerblue")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Dataset", override.aes = list(alpha=1, size = 2))) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(data = example, aes(x = variable, y = max(value, na.rm = T), label = group),
            position = position_dodge(width = 9.99), color = "black") +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales="free")
```

I put an important `width` to separate the different labels but they are still overlapping.

My question is then: how can I put the right label above the right boxplot for each facet of my plot ?

Comment: You don't have a variable in `geom_text` that represents the overlapping groups.  You could set `fill` globally or use `group = db` in `geom_text`.

Comment: This question seems indeed as duplicate now. I will close it. Thank you for the answer.